# Simple html select not working on android chrome

Tags: android, html, angular, google-chrome, html-select

I'm having trouble with google chrome for android.

My `select` tag in html doesn't work there, but it works on desktop google chrome and other browsers, even in safari and apple mobile devices, just not in google chrome for android.

I've tried other apps that have normal selects and they seem to work in mobile google chrome.

Here's an example of what's happening:

[image: Gif Image]

I have no idea how to fix this issue. If anyone could give me hints on what could be the reason.

This is the select:

```
<select class="form-control" name="cardType" ng-model="payment.cardType" required>
  <option value="AMEX">AMEX</option>
  <option value="DINE">DINE</option>
  <option value="DSVR">DSVR</option>
  <option value="MCRD">MCRD</option>
  <option value="VISA">VISA</option>
</select>
```

Comment: you could check the console log through android remote debugging: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/#enable_usb_debugging_on_your_android_device

Comment: What does this select has that the working one's does not?

Comment: @rtrigoso doesn't show any errors, tried inspecting the select and it seems normal.

Comment: @LGson the select doesn't have anything, if any, the selects that work have more stuff than this one, and every other select that I've tried works normally.

Comment: The single only thing then what comes to mind, is its values that might get  it blocked for security reasons. What if to change all card values/text to "abc1", "abc2", etc. and change the "card" and "payment" word to something else? ... had similar experience using the "ad" word in CSS rules, where those styles were blocked by adblocker

Comment: Did you try seeing if the click handler event gets called when you tap on the button? On the same devtools from chrome you can go the source window and check mark the click event. Then try to tap it and see if the event gets called.

Comment: @Johhan did you ever solve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: This may be relevant: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q4Rt6d0C4Qo

Comment: It looks to potentially be a problem with overlapping elements maybe? Or it could be that Angular doesn't like your option values, does this work on your device? https://codepen.io/jakebown/pen/jwWzeK

Comment: @JakeBown yes that works

Comment: Remove ng-model="payment.cardType" and try if it opens, if it does then your variable might not be initiated or some exception.

Also check if you have used  name="cardType" some where else

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52799817/bootstrap-dropdowns-not-working-on-android 

looks like your issue is related to this.